# Web application with client-side database

Tags: angular, database

I am developing an application for medical professionals. Due to the fact that I am treating with sensitive data and that I am using the server-side just for CRUD operations, I was wondering if it would be possible to serve the angular application to the user, and then store his data on his device (for example creating an instance of a database in the user's computer).

Do you think this would be feasible? Any ideas?
Thanks so much

Comment: You could play with SQLite in wasm https://github.com/kripken/sql.js/ combined with PWA (service worker) but there is always way that user remove - delete all persisted data or wrap app in electron, ionic ...

Comment: I should give anyway the possibility to the user to delete all his data due to GDPR... I will look deeper into electron, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for writing this as an answer, but it is just too much for a comment. I just want to say *beware*.

Forcing your clients to store their own sensitive data is a far less secure option than doing what every other bank, hospital, insurance company, etc... does by sending their data to remote servers that are professionally maintained and secured in data centers.

In the U.S.A. there are federal laws and regulations that limit how you handle sensitive personal data. Some of the most extreme & strict of those laws/regulations are found in the medical field.

**Don't think that just because you offload the data to your clients machines that it also offloads your legal (and ethical) responsibility to secure that data.**

Not sure where you plan to use this application, but you should very well check with the laws and regulations in your country.

Wish you the best!

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice! I am currently studying all the regulations about it, I was just curious about the feasibility of using javascript to easily distribute an application that would run locally on the client's devices

Answer (score 0):

When you store sensible data in local storage on device encrypt it with tools like

SubtleCrypto.encrypt()
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/encrypt

Example:
     const result = crypto.subtle.encrypt(algorithm, key, data);

Goal is to have a secure local container!